# Azure DevOps REST API - Not able to trigger pipeline via rest

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-pipelines

Trying to test Rest API to trigger via postman for Azure-Devops, getting below error. tried this for bash and getting similar error. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated

[Azure Devops trigger Pipeline via rest getting issue while triggering newly created pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67565167/azure-devops-trigger-pipeline-via-rest-getting-issue-while-triggering-newly-crea)

```
https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.1-preview.6
```

**Body**

```json
{
    "definition": {
        "id": 50
    }
}
```

**Error**

```json
{
   {
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: DefaultBranch",
    "typeName": "System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib",
    "typeKey": "ArgumentNullException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}
}
```

**YAML File**

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'package'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this body

```json
{
    "templateParameters": { "doReleaseBuild": "True" }, 
    "definition": {
        "id": 50
    },
    "sourceBranch": "refs/heads/main",
    "sourceVersion": "d265f01aeb4e677a25725f44f20ceb3ff1d7d767"
}
```

Don't forget to change `sourceVersion`.

Comment: ` {
    "$id": "1",
    "customProperties": {
        "ValidationResults": [
            {
                "result": "error",
                "message": "No pool was specified."
            }
        ]
    },
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildRequestValidationFailedException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi",
    "typeKey": "BuildRequestValidationFailedException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}`

Comment: I have tried this as well, getting this error

Comment: It just stays that you have an issue with your pipeline. It is incorrect because there is no pool specified.

Comment: But if you see I have already specified the pool in the YAML file

Comment: Well, I see your yaml. And you don't have to define pool in the body via REST call. Can you try to validate your YAML from the portal?